# How to apply aggregation and rbind on list of data.table?

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, lapply

I try to apply this reprex to the list of many data.table, with aggregation on many criteria.
I tried some combinaison of lapply, mapply, for, ... without success.

My input data is this list of data.table :

```
nb.row <- 50
nb.col <- 5
lst.DT <- replicate(5, as.data.table(matrix(runif(n=nb.row*nb.col, min = 0, max = 100), nb.row, nb.col)), simplify = FALSE)
crit <- as.data.table(replicate(3,sample(1:5,nb.row, replace = TRUE)))
names(crit) <- c("C1", "C2", "C3")
lst.DT <- lapply(lst.DT, cbind, crit)
```

The code I try to summarise, to simplify :

```
dt1.1 <- lst.DT[[1]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C1]
dt1.2 <- lst.DT[[1]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C2]
dt1.3 <- lst.DT[[1]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C3]

dt2.1 <- lst.DT[[2]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C1]
dt2.2 <- lst.DT[[2]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C2]
dt2.3 <- lst.DT[[2]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C3]

...

dtX.1 <- lst.DT[[X]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C1]
dtX.2 <- lst.DT[[X]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C2]
dtX.3 <- lst.DT[[X]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = C3]

res1 <- rbindlist(list(dt1.1, dt1.2, dt1.3))
res2 <- rbindlist(list(dt2.1, dt2.2, dt2.3))
...
resX <- rbindlist(list(dtX.1, dtX.2, dtX.3))
```

To finaly have in return a list with the same dimension as lst.DT, with res1, res2, ...

How to perform this kind of thing ?
Many thanks.

Comment: i ran rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2, dt3)) this its working ..are you not able to get the  "rbindlist"?

Comment: Oh yes, my reprex is running well. What I am looking to do, is to optimize writing. Schematically, loop through my list of data.table, then loop through the criteria (C1, C2, C3), with lapply, etc...

Comment: Still a bit unclear. What is the input data and what steps do you want to replace?

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my main post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example:

```
res1a <- rbindlist(
  lapply(
    paste0('C', 1:3),
    function(Ci) lst.DT[[1]][, .(new = sum(V4 / V5)), by = Ci]
  ), 
  use.names = FALSE
)
```

Another using `groupingsets()`:

```
vars <-  paste0('C', 1:3)
res1b <- groupingsets(
  lst.DT[[1]], j = sum(V4 / V5), by = vars, sets = as.list(vars)
)[, .(C1 = fcoalesce(.SD), new = V1), .SDcols = vars]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I give another analysis view for this problem. In a word, I focus on the list structure related with different column names **C1,C2,C3** and then rbind all lists.

```
library(data.table)
sumby <- function(list_in,col_name){
    lapply(list_in, function(x) x[,.(new = sum(V4/V5)), by = col_name])
}

lt1 <- sumby(lst.DT,"C1")
lt2 <- sumby(lst.DT,"C2")
lt3 <- sumby(lst.DT,"C3")

# unify df's name in list then rbind all list
lt2 <- lapply(lt2, function(x) x[,.(C1=C2,new)])
lt3 <- lapply(lt3, function(x) x[,.(C1=C3,new)])
resu1 <- mapply(rbind,lt1,lt2,lt3, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this.